# How to specify colors and line types using columns in dataframe when using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

My dataframe `df` includes variables `x`, `y`, `Color`, and `LineType`. Can I specify the color and the line type automatically by the columns in `df`, while plotting line+marker chart with **ggplot2**?

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x, y, Color, LineType)

P <- ggplot(DATA, aes(x=x.Years, y=y)) +
  geom_point(size=5, aes(color=Color)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Color, linetype=LineType), size=2)
```

The code above doesn't work. There are two colors in `Color` and two line types in `LineType`, but everything come out red and in solid lines. What did I do wrong? How can I synchronize the plotting features of each data point?

Comment: what do you mean by there are two colors in Color? There are two factors or you specified two colors?

Comment: @StupidWolf Yeah there're two factors in `Color`

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure what you mean or what went wrong with your plot, but if you want to manually specify colors using a data.frame, you do:

```
DATA = data.frame(x.Years=rep(1:5,2),y=c(1:5,8:12),
Color=rep(c("#dd7631","#708160"),each=5),
LineType = rep(c("dotted","dashed"),each=5))

ggplot(DATA,aes(x=x.Years,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(color=Color)) +
geom_line(aes(color=Color,linetype=LineType)) + 
scale_color_identity() + scale_linetype_identity()
```

[image]